# Java how to read bytes into String

Tags: java, linux, filesystems, kernel

How do I read this information in Java and convert it into a readable format?

Could anyone please give me some idea where to start?

```
5200 0000 5300 0000 5400 0000 c51e a406
0200 0400 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
5220 0000 5320 0000 5420 0000 ba1e 9e06
0900 0400 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
0140 0000 0240 0000 0340 0000 270f 4b06
0100 0400 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

EDIT:
It's an ex2 filesystem. (It's a 20,480KB file(filesystem) where most of it contain just 0000 0000 0000 0000).

EDIT2: I'm trying to understand how an ex2 filesystem is laid out on disk and how both files and directories can be located and read. If anyone could briefly explain this to me would be much appreciated.

EDIT3: I've found some libraries that might help but not quite sure it they are useful of what I want?

```
java.nio.ByteBuffer
java.nio.ByteOrder
java.nio.channels.FileChannel
java.nio.file.FileSystems
```

Comment: What do you mean by readable? What kind of data is this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a hexadecimal memory output that can be read in many different ways. First thing you need to figure out is how it was written. But if you just want an ASCII convert from hex you can just use an ASCII table as a reference ;)

final edit: check out this website on ext2 filesystem http://www.nongnu.org/ext2-doc/ext2.html